# How do I handle a global shortcut and filemenu item click event in electronjs from renderer file?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Here

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut explains how to handle a global shortcut from index.ts

but how do I send it back to my actual DOM based code by handling it in my render.js?

Also, I need to use a Save/Save As and Load file... in File Menu.
The content is inside index.html as textarea.

It was easy to communicate from renderer.ts to index.ts (I'm using the electron-forge with typescript integration) but how am I suppose to do the opposite ?

Comment: are you saying you want your web code to handle the event after it's handled by the global shortcut handling? Can you not just add keydown listeners in your DOM

Comment: yes this is what I'm saying. Sure I could do it the way you said but what If I have this shortcut attached to a file menu item btw?

Comment: Also I use a custom text area called code mirror which prevents ctrl+tab from handling it